# Remove [windows-system] tag

Tags: support, tags

[windows-system](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-system) was just created for [a question put on hold as unclear](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/179262/43319), and I see no reason to have OS-specific tags. Indeed there are none for any other OSs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to do anything. The question has been deleted, and a tag with no questions is auto-deleted by a cron job.